# tf.nn.top_k loss order. but i want maintain tensor's order

Tags: python, tensorflow

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

test = np.random.randint(50, size=60)
test = test.reshape(3,4,5)

sess = tf.Session()
with sess.as_default():
    test_tensor = tf.constant(test)
    value, indices = tf.nn.top_k(test_tensor,2,sorted = True)
    print((value.eval()))
```

input :

```
test : array([[[21, 10, 25,  7, 46],
    [26, 28, 39, 16, 15],
    [49,  6, 49, 39,  9],
    [33, 15, 14, 27, 40]],...]
```

what_i_want_value :

```
[[25,46],[28,39],[49,49],[33,40] ...]
```

but

```
value : [[[46, 25],[39, 28],[49, 49],[40, 33], ...]
```

So, How can I implement order maintaining top_k ?

i tried to np.argsort but it's hard to me accessing 2-dimentional index.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Use `sorted=False`.

Comment: @jdehesa Thanks, but I think sorted doesn't work.

Comment: Well when I tested the `test` array with your code changing `sorted=True` with `sorted=False` the result was what you describe in `what_i_want_value`. What is it that is not working for you?